# lxml.etree: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I want to take some simple xml files and convert them all to CSV in one go (though this code is just for one at a time). It looks to me like there are no official name spaces, but I'm not sure.
I have this code (I used one header, `SubmittingSystemVendor`, but I really want to write all of them to CSV:

```
import csv
import lxml.etree
x = r'C:\Users\...\jh944.xml'

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow('SubmittingSystemVendor')
    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(x)

    writer.writerow(row)
```

Here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EOYGeneralCollectionGroup SchemaVersionMajor="2014-2015" SchemaVersionMinor="1" CollectionId="157" SubmittingSystemName="MISTAR" SubmittingSystemVendor="WayneRESA" SubmittingSystemVersion="2014" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://cepi.state.mi.us/msdsxml/EOYGeneralCollection2014-20151.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EOYGeneralCollection>
        <SubmittingEntity>
            <SubmittingEntityTypeCode>D</SubmittingEntityTypeCode>
            <SubmittingEntityCode>82730</SubmittingEntityCode>
        </SubmittingEntity>
```

The error is:

> lxml.etree: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using `lxml.etree.fromstring`, but giving it a file path as the argument.  This means it's trying to interpret "C:\Users...\jh944.xml" as the XML data to be parsed.

Instead, you want to open the file *containing* this XML.  You can simply replace the call to `fromstring` with `lxml.etree.parse`, which will accept a filename or open file object as the argument.

Comment: If I then want to proceed with writing the parsed XML file to CSV, can you provide assistance? I've created a new question here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514049/python-3-4-lxml-etree-to-csv-all-columns?noredirect=1#comment52887304_32514049

Comment: You will want to iterate through the nodes and then get the text value of each child element, and pass it through to the CSVWriter.  (eg. `for node in root.findall("EOYGeneralCollection/SubmittingEntity"): writer.writerow([subnode.text for subnode in node])` may be enough for very simple cases.